# Why is referencing a column (as a left-hand operand) that is not part of the table being queried not an error in the EXISTS operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, exists

Given this SQL batch:

```
CREATE TABLE #source
(
  ID int,
  SourceDescr varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO #source
VALUES
(1, 'first'),
(2, 'second')


CREATE TABLE #target
(
  ID int,
  TargetDescr varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO #target
SELECT * FROM #source

INSERT INTO #target
SELECT * FROM #source S
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM #target
  WHERE SourceDescr = S.SourceDescr
  --       /\ How is this not an error?
)
```

Why does the `WHERE` clause in the `EXISTS` operator work? Surely there is no `SourceDescr` column in the `#target` table.

I even tried this and it also works:

```
INSERT INTO #target
SELECT * FROM #source S
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT SourceDescr -- ??
  FROM #target
  WHERE SourceDescr = S.SourceDescr
)
```

Reading the official [documentation for EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) did not clarify this for me.

Thanks.

Comment: `WHERE SourceDescr = S.SourceDescr` is equivalent to `WHERE S.SourceDescr = S.SourceDescr` which is always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is explained in the documentation: [Subqueries (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017):

> column names in a statement are implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause at the same level. If a column does not exist in the table referenced in the FROM clause of a subquery, it is implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause of the outer query.

Answer (score 3):

This is interpreted as:

```
INSERT INTO #target
    SELECT S.*
    FROM #source S
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1
      FROM #target
      WHERE S.SourceDescr = S.SourceDescr
    );
```

It runs, but it does not do what you intend.

This is one reason why I advise using qualified column names for *all* column references in *all* your queries.  Your intended logic:

```
INSERT INTO #target
    SELECT S.*
    FROM #source S
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1
      FROM #target t
      WHERE t.SourceDescr = S.SourceDescr
    );
```

would generate a compile-time error and never execute.